# Send an email with CSV attachemt in SQL Server(SQL Job is failing)

Tags: sql, sql-server

When we run below script manually we are getting an email with attachment but when we are running through SQL Job getting below error.

> Executed as user:venu: Failed to initialize the sqlcmd library with
>   error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).  The step
>   failed.

```
      /* To send an Email Attachment to the User */
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @profile_name                = 'DBMail',
           @recipients                  = 'venu.siripuram@gamil.com',
           @query                       = 'SET NOCOUNT ON
                                           Select Recordtype as TransType, SKU, SKU1 Style, SKU2 Color, 
                                                  SKU3 Size, UPC
                                           from CIMSDE.dbo.ExportTransactions with (nolock)',
           @subject                     = 'SKU Transactions',
           @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
           @query_attachment_filename   = 'sample.csv',
           @query_result_separator      = '',
           @query_result_no_padding     = 1
```

Comment: Just a guess, but how about a fully qualified path?

Comment: Take a peek at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99326/sp-send-dbmail-stored-procedure-send-with-attachment

Comment: Also, you may want to change the job to execute as the `sa` account.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error was due to '**File size limit was exceeded**'.

You can set the file size (in **bytes**) using the following command:

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'MaxFileSize', '10000000';
```

you can get all set values by executing the following:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_configure_sp
```

Comment: No, still getting the same issue
Message
Executed as user: . Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).  The step failed.

Comment: @venusiripuram Please see if https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/66d6ec22-644b-43a1-b394-504e3e5d9f23/sql-server-agent-job-and-database-mail-error-formatting-query-probably-invalid-paramters?forum=sqldatabaseengine helps.